# How to use FindReplace for specify sheetname by Google API V4 Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to use Python to update the filename and spreadsheet ID saved in a Google Sheet when I upload files to my Drive according to the `sheetName` in the Sheet, and I want to delete or replace a row with a duplicate name when I upload my files (so that the newest file ID is updated with same date).

I have been using [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#python), but I can only replace the same column but not the same row, and only in the first sheet of my spreadsheet.

Here's the script:

```py
#file_name and file_ID: obtain when upload the files,
def update(file_name, file_ID):

    range_name = file_name + "!A:B"

    requests = []
    requests.append([{
        "findReplace": {
            "find": Date,
            "replacement": FileID,
            "matchCase": True,
            "matchEntireCell": True,
            "searchByRegex": True,
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 1
            },
        }
    }])

    body = {"requests": [requests]}
    response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
    pprint(response)
```

Is there any way I can use to find if the name is column A in the "filetype1" sheet (need match the Sheet Name to determine under which sheet first), then replace the ID in column B?

[image: Example sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comprehend that you have a table where you want to search for a `Date` and change its `ID` value of the same row. If understood it correctly, you would need to use [`Values.get()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) and [`Values.update()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) methods.

First you will need to use `get` to read the full table. Parse it with Python and substitute the appropriate values. After that operation you can upload the full table as an `update` request. Please, don't hesitate to ask me any follow-up questions.